# Python 2.7 script compiling to .exe that uses many packages, including Matplotlib and PyQt4

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, compilation, pyqt4, exe

I'm trying to compile a Python 2.7 script that imports the following packages:

```
import easygui as EG

import numpy as np
import pandas

from skimage import data
from skimage import measure

import cv2

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

import ntpath
import os
import time

# Packages for progress bar
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot,SIGNAL,SLOT
```

- easygui
- numpy
- pandas
- skimage
- opencv (cv2)
- matplotlib
- numpy
- ntpath
- os
- time
- sys
- PyQt4.QtGui
- PyQt4.QtCore

All of my sub-functions are in the one "GUI.py" script, and runs perfectly when I use the normal IDE, but I can't seem to get it to compile properly.

I have tried to use cx_freeze as described [here](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils), and pyInstaller through what was described [here](https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script). Both did compile and a "GUI.exe" file was made, but it did not work when I tried to run it.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

I'm using Python 2.7 Win 64 and I use Anaconda 2.

Comment: Please help! I noticed that [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720066/creating-exe-file-with-cx-freeze-pyqt4-matplotlib-and-multiple-py-files-does?answertab=active#tab-top) had issues with the same thing and there has been no help given. And that one was months ago!

Comment: "but it did not work when I tried to run it" is not a sufficient problem description. What was the error? You can try to create a minimal example only using subsets of the packages and see which package causes the error or if it is even package related and not a problem in your code.